# Does the Cloud Vision API support TIFF & PDF label detection yet?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

The documentation here https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files states PDF & TIFF are supported.
Using the Node.js client library I get an error response code:3 & message:'Bad image data.' for TIFFs and PDFs but all other file types are accepted and labeled.
I'm using local files not cloud storage e.g.

```
const [result] = await client.labelDetection('./test.pdf');
```

Neither of the "Try it!" demo pages will allow upload of TIFF or PDF either.

Comment: So as Felix details below, label detection for TIFF & PDF is supported, but only using the "Online small batch" method.
An alternative is to simply convert TIFF & PDF to a fully supported format instead.  Large files can also be downsized at the same time and in my situation conversion and upload was quicker than uploading the original anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the Vision API supports PDF and TIFF formats, there are some considerations you should be mindful of. Quoting the official documentation linked:

1. > Currently DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION and TEXT_DETECTION are the only feature types available for [offline (asynchronous) large batch](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) file (PDF/TIFF) annotation.

Alternatively,

2. > [Online small batch annotation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/file-small-batch) is available for all [Vision features](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/file-small-batch#features).

Bear in mind that small batch is limited to files not larger than 5 PDF/TIFF pages.
You can find examples of how to implement this in `Node.js` in the links above.

Additionally, I was able to successfully run [this *Try it*](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/file-small-batch?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22inputConfig%22%3A%7B%22gcsSource%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22gs%3A%2F%2Fcloud-samples-data%2Fvision%2Fdocument_understanding%2Fcustom_0773375000.pdf%22%7D%2C%22mimeType%22%3A%22application%2Fpdf%22%7D%2C%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22LABEL_DETECTION%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22CROP_HINTS%22%7D%5D%2C%22pages%22%3A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D#try_it) demo.